# SQL INDEX not used on WHERE ABS(x-y) < k condition, but used on y - k < x < y + k condition

Tags: sql, indexing, sqlite, explain

I have a query involving [couples of rows which have a less-than-2-hours time-difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49866217/1422096) (~0.08333 days):

```
SELECT mt1.*, mt2.* FROM mytable mt1, mytable mt2 
                    WHERE ABS(JULIANDAY(mt1.date) - JULIANDAY(mt2.date)) < 0.08333
```

This query is rather slow, i.e. ~ 1 second (the table has ~ 10k rows).

An idea was to use an `INDEX`. Obviously `CREATE INDEX id1 ON mytable(date)` didn't improve anything, that's normal.

---

Then I noticed that the magical query `CREATE INDEX id2 ON mytable(JULIANDAY(date))`

1. didn't help when using:

   ```
   ... WHERE ABS(JULIANDAY(mt1.date) - JULIANDAY(mt2.date)) < 0.08333
   ```
2. didn't help when using:

   ```
   ... WHERE JULIANDAY(mt2.date) - 0.08333 < JULIANDAY(mt1.date) < JULIANDAY(mt2.date) + 0.08333
   ```
3. ... but massively improved the performance (query time happily divided by 50 !) when using:

   ```
   ... WHERE JULIANDAY(mt1.date) < JULIANDAY(mt2.date) + 0.08333
         AND JULIANDAY(mt1.date) > JULIANDAY(mt2.date) - 0.08333
   ```

Of course 1., 2. and 3. are equivalent since mathematically,

```
|x-y| < 0.08333 <=> y - 0.08333 < x < y + 0.08333
                <=> x < y + 0.08333 AND x > y - 0.08333
```

**Question: Why are solutions 1. and 2. not making use of INDEX whereas solution 3. is using it?**

---

Note:

- I'm using Python + Sqlite `sqlite3` module
- The fact solutions 1. and 2. are not using the index is confirmed when doing `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT ...`:

  ```
  (0, 0, 0, u'SCAN TABLE mytable AS mt1')
  (0, 1, 1, u'SCAN TABLE mytable AS mt2')
  ```

  The fact solution 3. is using the index is shown when doing `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT ...`:

  ```
  (0, 0, 1, u'SCAN TABLE mytable AS mt2')
  (0, 1, 0, u'SEARCH TABLE mytable AS mt1 USING INDEX id2 (<expr>>? AND <expr><?)')
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the inclusion of **`AND`** is the reasoning as per :

> The WHERE clause on a query is broken up into "terms" where each term
>   is separated from the others by an AND operator. If the WHERE clause
>   is composed of constraints separate by the OR operator then the entire
>   clause is considered to be a single "term" to which the OR-clause
>   optimization is applied.

[The SQLite Query Optimizer Overview](https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html)

It may be worthwhile running [`ANALYZE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) to see if that improves matters.

As per the comment:

> I think the previously added paragraph can clarify why ABS(x-y) < k is
>   not using index, and why x < y + k is using it, don't you think so?
>   Would you want to include this paragraph? [All terms of the WHERE
>   clause are analyzed to see if they can be satisfied using indices. To
>   be usable by an index a term must be of one of the following forms:
>   column = expression, column IS expression, column > expression ...

The following has been added.

> To be usable by an index a term must be of one of the following forms:
>    column = expression
>    column IS expression
>    column > expression
>    column >= expression
>    column < expression
>    column <= expression
>    expression = column
>    expression > column
>    expression >= column
>    expression < column
>    expression <= column
>    column IN (expression-list)
>    column IN (subquery)
>    column IS NULL

I'm not sure if it would work with a [`BETWEEN`](https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#the_between_optimization) (e.g. `WHERE column BETWEEN expr1 AND expr2`).

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I think you can remove the `As per the comment: I think the previously added ...` paragraph -> this was just in comment/discussion/"chat mode", and not relevant to the technical discussion/"answer form". The appropriate accreditation would be https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#where_clause_analysis.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an expression index.
The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/expridx.html) says:

> The SQLite query planner will consider using an index on an expression when the expression that is indexed appears in the WHERE clause or in the ORDER BY clause of a query, *exactly* as it is written in the CREATE INDEX statement. The query planner does not do algebra.

So it is not possible to use an index to speed up lookups of a call to `abs()` if the indexed expression is only a parameter. (And it is not possible to index the entire `abs()` call because it involves two tables.)

So converting the expression as you did is the only way to make it more efficient.

(Please note that `a<b<c` compares `a` and `b` first, and then compares the resulting boolean value against `c`. This is not what you want.)