# CREATE INDEX on a function applied to a column: works on one install, not the other

Tags: python, sql, indexing, sqlite

When doing this on Windows (sqlite3.version is 2.6.0, sqlite3.sqlite_version is 3.23.1):

```
import sqlite3, datetime
db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
c = db.cursor()
c.execute('CREATE TABLE mytable (id integer, date timestamp)')
c.execute('INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (1, ?)', (datetime.datetime(2018,1,1,12,11,29),))

c.execute('CREATE INDEX id1 ON mytable(JULIANDAY(date))')
```

it works (the fact of having an INDEX on `JULIANDAY(date)` and not on `date` is useful because of this [question+answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49887709/1422096)).

When doing the same on Linux (sqlite3.version is 2.6.0, sqlite3.sqlite_version is 3.8.2), I get:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

**Is creating an INDEX on `JULIANDAY(date)` in this version?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/expridx.html#compatibility), the ability to create indexes on expressions was introduced in SQLite 3.9.0 - so you won't be able to use it in the 3.8.2 version you have installed on your linux machine.

Comment: Linked 
question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49820873/upgrade-pythons-sqlite3-on-debian